# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'con''(void)" (??__Econ@@YAXXZ)

Tags: c++, mysql

I am tring to connect to a MySQL database from Visual Studio 2013 C++.
I included the MySQL "include" folder in Property -> C/C++ -> MySQL\include and in Linker -> Input -> MySQL\lib\libmysql.lib.
But I got the following error in mysql_com.h, in this line:

```
  my_socket fd;                 /* For Perl DBI/dbd */
```

Error:

```
1>d:\web_server\mysql\include\mysql_com.h(320): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'fd'
1>d:\web_server\mysql\include\mysql_com.h(320): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

If I comment this line (//) -> no error;
But if I try to add

```
MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
```

to code, I get:

```
1>mysqltest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'con''(void)" (??__Econ@@YAXXZ)
1>D:\Info\cvis\mysqltest\Debug\mysqltest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648344/mysql-connection-with-visual-studio-c), but no good result.

Help :D ?

Comment: Try adding this #define CPPCONN_LIB_BUILD // MySQL Connectors static lib, before including the mysql headers

Comment: Add include folder and link library for both release and debug targets.

Comment: Yeah.. with c++ connector I couldn't do anything. The c connector works well :). Thank you !

Comment: I've same issue. Did you solve this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't remember much what I've done next.